# Weird glitch after copying from a CSV file?

Tags: csv, libreoffice-calc

I was doing a programming job that involved writing data to a large CSV file (700 MB). I occasionally opened the file using libre office to check the data coming in.

This morning I opened the file (while it was being written to) and copied some data to another empty csv file so I can write a script to read the data from it properly, so I can be ready for when the large CSV file is ready.

However, after I copied an example row over, I closed the large file and the re-opened it a few minutes later and now my data looks like this in the preview:

[image]

Which is impressive as I do not have any chinese or japanese characters in my data at all. Opening the file in libre office calc  gives me a "too many characters in cell" message, hanging and then libre office crashes.

If I look at the file in bash, it looks like this:
[image]

Correct words showing and everything. If I read the file using a python script or open as a text file, it shows the rows correctly as well. What is this strange error?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I was being silly, the character set was changed to unicode and I did not notice.

Doy.

Comment: @Ramhound Please pay more attention. The answer is 1/ posted by the OP 2/ It does answer his own question.